# HackerRank: My QuickSort algorithm is too slow

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

Can someone please explain to me why this QuickSort algorithm has bad performance?

I followed a tutorial from Derek Banas so I thought it would optimal.

```
public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right){
    if(left>=right) return;
    int pivot = arr[right];
    int index = partition(arr, left, right, pivot);
    quickSort(arr, left, index-1);
    quickSort(arr, index+1, right);
}

private static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right, int pivot){
    int leftPointer = left-1;
    int rightPointer = right;
    while(true){
        while(arr[++leftPointer]<pivot && leftPointer<=rightPointer); 
        while(arr[--rightPointer]>pivot && rightPointer>leftPointer); 
        if(leftPointer>=rightPointer) break;
        else{
            //swap values
            int temp = arr[leftPointer];
            arr[leftPointer] = arr[rightPointer];
            arr[rightPointer] = temp;
        }
    }
    int tempP = arr[leftPointer];
    arr[leftPointer] = arr[right];
    arr[right] = tempP;
    return leftPointer;

}
```

Comment: Your partition logic doesn't seem to be `O(n)`

Comment: It is valid Java code.

Can you expand on how I can make it 0(n)?

Comment: Looks O(n) to me.

Comment: If the array is partially or completely sorted already, selecting the rightmost element as pivot is inefficient. Take it from the middle of the interval or randomly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot and even more extreme https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians  The point is that the worst case performance of a quicksort depends heavily on how the pivot is chosen. HackerRank is almost certainly going to give you inputs that require more work to choose a good pivot.

Comment: Multiple while loops making this partition inefficient. This could be solved using only one loop.

Comment: Is that three nested while loops? If so, that’s likely a problem.

Comment: @suvojit_007: I disagree. The number of while loops is not a good measure of (in)efficiency.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It seems I need to be more tactful selecting the pivot.

Comment: If you need even more speed, consider that production quicksort implementations will switch to insertion sort when the array size is small. For example, `if (right - left < 10) { insertionSort(arr, left, right); return; }`. That will save a whole bunch of recursive calls on tiny arrays. See the final paragraph [in this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Relation_to_other_sorting_algorithms).